# Why am I unable to install custom Slack app requesting chat:write:public?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am writing a custom slack app.

I need the bot to be able to post to any channel without requiring an invitation.

In the OAuth flow (https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize), I am requesting the following scopes:

- chat:write
- chat:write:public

When I only request "chat:write", I am able to complete the OAuth flow and add the app to the workspace.

However, when I additionally request "chat:write:public", the OAuth flow fails:

> Invalid permissions requested
> invalid_scope

[image]

Are there additional steps required to allow "chat:write:public" as a scope?

Comment: Is the channel where you attempt to write to public?

Comment: The issue occurs in the OAuth flow installing the app -- before I even attempt to write the message. (Question updated to reflect this).

Comment: The scope name must be "chat:write.public" (period in front of "public")